# Return a double value from an array element to the console

Tags: c++, arrays

I have some code where `norms` is declared as a double array of size 3 x 2.  I would like to output `norms[0]` to the console.

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
    
double norms[3][2];
_cal_norm(dept,size,max_posn,norms[0]);
cout << norms[0];
```

I would like to have the double value returned. I have tried using `cout << norms[0]` to return it.  But it returns the following instead:

> norms[0] 1 0x7fff33d52180

Is there a way for me to see the double value?

Comment: If you want to print the two values in the `norms[0]` subarray, then print them both: `std::cout << norms[0][0] << " " << norms[0][1] << std::endl;` Otherwise, you're asking to print the *address* of the subarray.

Comment: I think you mean `norms[0][0]`. `norms` is a two-dimensional array; `norms[0]` is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: You need a loop of some sort. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311149/how-to-print-2d-arrays-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311149/how-to-print-2d-arrays-in-c)

Comment: Unrelated, but all identifiers that are in the global namespace with leading underscores are reserved, and using such a name has undefined behavior.  You should _not_ call your function _cal_norm().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`norms` is a 2-dimensional array of arrays, so `norms[0]` is the 1st inner array in the outer array.  If you use `cout << norms[0];`, it will print the address of that first array. That's why you got a hexadecimal number. If your goal is to print a number in a 2D array then you should write `cout << norms[0][0];` which will print out the 1st value of the 1st array in `norms`, for example.